# How to access child context in parent templates?

Tags: meteor

If child template defined something in `onCreated`,

```
Template.test.onCreated(function() {
  this.xxx = 'test';
});
```

And I want to access child context in parent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Session or ReactiveVar for this operation. But if you need to save it on the child template I think you could use:

```
var childView = Blaze.getView(currentTemplate.find('#your-child-theme-id'));
```

and then get template instance by:

```
var childTemplateInstance = childView._templateInstance;
```

and then

```
var myXXXvar = childTemplateInstance.xxx;
```

But this is a little bit dirty :/ I don't think there is a Meteor API for this particular use case. I think you should play with reactive vars or client only collections etc. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve.